# I want to remove these untracked files

Tags: git

[image]

These only showing me permission denied and I am unable to remove this bug.

I used git clean -n command to remove this but it's not working.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the directory in which that project was started. It appears from the message as if it might have been started in your user directory. Also add the directory path to the project you are trying to use git for.

Answer (score 0):

`git clean -xdf` will do what you'd like.

`git clean -n` just shows you what files *would* be cleaned on invoking `git clean`

Comment: I tried to run 'git clean -xdf' but it shows failed to remove and also shows permission denied @buratino

Comment: Sounds like your permissions are wonky.  The short answer here would be to try `sudo git clean -xdf`